# Ubuntu boot process hangs on starting snappy daemon

Tags: boot, ubuntu-core

**TL;DR:** Ubuntu boot hangs on starting the snappy daemon, takes roughly 5min to boot, reinstall doesn't fix, issue is caused by an update.

---

Backstory: I installed the vanilla-gnome-session and after deciding I didn't like it removed it again. I later had installed and removed ubuntu-gnome-session hoping that it would bring back the old login screen. After that I did an update before reboot. Upon shutdown the loading screen for ubuntu gnome appeared and was running a kernel upgrade. Then when booting again the loading boot screen for ubuntu froze, switching to TTY2 revealed that it hung on three jobs:

```
A start job is running for
* Snappy daemon
* Wait until snapd is fully seeded
* Hold until boot process finishes up
```

It takes roughly 5min until this process is finished.

After some unsuccesful troubleshooting decided to reinstall. I first used the reinstall option from the live install disc and after finishing the PC booted fine even after a reboot. However as soon as I ran `apt update && apt upgrade` it would hang again.

Some goes after doing a complete reinstall (choosing "erase disk and install" on the install disc)

---

[System info generated with Hardinfo](http://output.jsbin.com/yeyoyogisa/1)

[RAW](https://pastebin.com/VRDUZfLi)